# SQL Server - Update All Records, Per Group, With Result of SubQuery

Tags: sql-server

If anyone could even just help me phrase this question better I'd appreciate it.

I have a SQL Server table, let's call it cars, which contains entries representing items and information about their owners including car_id, owner_accountNumber, owner_numCars.

We're using a system that sorts 'importantness of owner' based on number of cars owned, and relies on the owner_numCars column to do so. I'd rather not adjust this, if reasonably possible.

Is there a way I can update owner_numCars per owner_accountNumber using a stored procedure? Maybe some other more efficient way I can accomplish every owner_numCars containing the count of entries per owner_accountNumber?

Right now the only way I can think to do this is to (from the c# application):

```
SELECT owner_accountNumber, COUNT(*)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY owner_accountNumber;
```

and then foreach row returned by that query

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET owner_numCars = <count result> 
WHERE owner_accountNumber = <accountNumber result>
```

But this seems wildly inefficient compared to having the server handle the logic and updates.

Edit - Thanks for all the help. I know this isn't really a well set up database, but it's what I have to work with. I appreciate everyone's input and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution takes into account that you want to keep the owner_numCars column in the CARs table and that the column should always be accurate in real time.

I'm defining table CARS as a table with attributes about cars including it's current owner.  The number of cars owned by the current owner is de-normalized into this table.  Say I, LAS, own three cars, then there are three entries in table CARS, as such:

```
    car_id    owner_accountNumber    owner_numCars
      1         LAS1                     3
      2         LAS1                     3
      3         LAS1                     3
```

For owner_numCars to be used as an importance factor in a live interface, you'd need to update owner_numCars for every car every time LAS1 sells or buys a car or is removed from or added to a row.

Note you need to update CARS for both the old and new owners.  If Sam buys car1, both Sam's and LAS' totals need to be updated.

You can use this procedure to update the rows.  This SP is very context sensitive.  It needs to be called after rows have been deleted or inserted for the deleted or inserted owner.   When an owner is updated, it needs to be called for both the old and new owners.

To update real time as accounts change owners:

```
create procedure update_car_count 
@p_acct nvarchar(50)  -- use your actual datatype here

AS

    update CARS 
    set owner_numCars = (select count(*) from CARS where owner_accountNumber = @p_acct)
    where owner_accountNumber = @p_acct;

GO
```

To update all account_owners:

```
create procedure update_car_count_all
AS

    update C
    set owner_numCars = (select count(*) from CARS where owner_acctNumber = C.owner_acctNumber)
    from CARS C
GO
```

Comment: you have a valid point that if you want to maintain millions of records and having a cached de-normalized value that it would be best to maintain that value during an insert/update/delete.  And 1 place to do that would be in a stored procedure.  However a derived column would still not be any significant difference vs window function when dealing with a single owner_accountNumber at a time.  Expand your answer and show how a stored procedure could be written.  Or and I typically hate saying this a trigger.  because SP unless using custom type wouldn't allow for multiple row changes

Comment: Yes, I see your point.  I wouldn't design it this way.  I thought of triggers but didn't want to get in that topic here.

Comment: agreed I do almost everything possible to stay away from triggers especially when dealing with millions of rows :)

Comment: I think this is what I was trying to come up with. Is there any way to write this such that it runs for each distinct owner_accountNumber, or would I have to call this procedure for each, piping in the account? This update would get run after reading in a large (for me, anyway. Maybe 50,000 records per batch isn't really a lot) dump of customer data and if I can avoid 15,000 calls from my app to the server I think it'd save a fair chunk of time.

Comment: @user8675309 I added a procedure that will update every distinct owner_acctNumber or every row in the table.  I stayed true to my original code but one of the other answers may be better if you're really wanting to update all owners which will also be all rows.  I don't advise storing a value that isn't updated in real time.  Agree with Rominus on that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways of doing this.  Here is one way using `COUNT() OVER` window function and an updatable `Common Table Expression [CTE]`.  That you won't have to worry about relating data back, ids etc.

```
;WITH cteCarCounts AS (
    SELECT
       owner_accountNumber
       ,owner_numCars
       ,NewNumberOfCars = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY owner_accountNumber)
    FROM
       MyTable
)

UPDATE cteCarCounts
SET owner_numCars =  NewNumberOfCars
```

However, from a design perspective I would raise the question of whether this value (owner_numCars) should be on this table or on what I assume would be the owner table.

Rominus did make a good point of using a view if you want the data to always reflect the current value.  You could also use also do it with a table valued function which could be more performant than a view.  But if you are simply showing it then you could simply do something like this:

```
SELECT
   owner_accountNumber
   ,owner_numCars = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY owner_accountNumber)
FROM
   MyTable
```

By adding a where clause to either the CTE or the SELECT statement you will effectively limit your dataset and the solution should remain fast. E.g.

```
WHERE owner_accountNumber = @owner_accountNumber
```

Comment: This solution updates every row.  If there are millions of records and the column needs to be maintained real time, it won't scale well.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a View.  If you don't know, a View is a virtual table that displays/calculates data from a real table that is continously updated as the table data updates.  So if you want to see your table with `owner_numCars` added you could do:

```
SELECT a.*, b.owner_numCars
from mytable as a
inner join
    (SELECT owner_accountNumber, COUNT(*) as owner_numCars 
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY owner_accountNumber) as b
on a.owner_accountNumber = b.owner_accountNumber
```

You'd want to remove the `owner_numCars` column from the real table since you don't need to actually store that data on each row.  If you can't remove it you can replace `a.*` with an explicit list of all the fields except `owner_numCars`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to run SQL to update this value. What if it doesn't run for a long time? What if someone loads a lot of data and then runs the score and finds a guy that has 100 cars counts as a zero b/c the update didn't run.  Data should only live in 1 place, updating has it living in 2.  You want a view that pulls this value from the tables as it is needed.

```
CREATE VIEW vOwnersInfo
AS
SELECT o.*, 
ISNULL(c.Cnt,0) AS Cnt
FROM OWNERS o
LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT OwnerId, 
       COUNT(1) AS Cnt
       FROM Cars
       GROUP BY OwnerId) AS c
ON o.OwnerId = c.OwnerId
```

Comment: While I agree having this data live in the cars table is bad.  Considered a flattened fact table for OLAP data model.  There are times when it could be necessary to have the value replicated like that which could potentially speed up SSAS queries and take advantage of a column index store

Comment: @Matt You are correct, an OLAP data model could need to break 3rd normal form. I don't think this is one of those cases. The answer to everything starts with "It depends..."